# Saving the out of tail

Tags: redirect, grep, tail

The following does not work...

```
tail -f /var/log/mysql/general.log | grep Connect > /home/myfile.txt
```

If I remove the "-f" switch then I am able to save the output to a text file, but it does not work wile tail is running.

Nor does tee works

```
tail -f /var/log/mysql/general.log | grep Connect -tee "/home/myfile.txt"
```

**update**

Command provided by quanta does work.

```
tail -f /var/log/mysql/general.log | tee >(grep Connect > /home/myfile.txt)
```

But I have to keep the window open. nohup tail -f ... does not seem to work.
How do I keep this command running continuously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tail -f /var/log/mysql/general.log | tee >(grep Connect > /home/myfile.txt)
```

Comment: Updated my question. will nohup work with this command?

Comment: No need to use `nohup`. `tail -f` will run continuously until you stop it by pressing `Ctrl+C`.

Comment: When I close the putty window, it seems to be killing the process

Comment: OK. I misunderstand you mean. Read the SvenW's [answer](http://serverfault.com/questions/298710/saving-the-out-of-tail/298726#298726).

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it works just fine.

The problem is probably that the output is buffered along each step so you'll need to have a lot of output before it actually gets flushed to the file.

Comment: You can use `grep --line-buffered Connect > /home/myfile.txt`.

Comment: Right, should have mentioned that. No option for tail though.

Comment: `grep` without `--line-buffered` didn't work on my system. Does it works for you?

Answer (score 1):

About your nohup problem: If you don't want to see the output continuously for some reason, I wouldn't  create a separate file with part of the logs (which is essentially what you are doing), but create the extraction on demand with just a grep command.

If you insist on your method, you could use `screen` or  `tmux` to run your command.